# Smoothly handle access to secure site via VPN or Fixed IP

Tags: networking, apache2, cloudflare

I am starting to sell a service, from a secure site to clients. Some have access via fixed IPs from their offices, some have VPN (softEther) access. I also have redundancy and hot cut over. Currently these all have different IP addresses which I have set as subdomains. I want to be able to give my customer one link, e.g. TheirCompany.myService.com

If they go to https://TheirCompany.myService.com from their fixed IP address, it should use company00**0**.myservice.com. If they are logged into their VPN, it should seamlessly go to company00**1**.myservice.com. If server1 is down, use server2. (If none are accessible it should give some helpful login instructions.)

My current thinking is I need **yet another** public facing page TheirCompany.myService.com which will test with javascript all the options and redirect as appropriate. Am I missing something clever with Apache or Cloudflare that could do this work for me?

Comment: Well if the subdomain have to go live *immidiately*, then you will need a very short TTL setting in DNS, so the FQDN do not get cached.

Comment: Not sure this answers it - we cannot be changing the subdomain (even rapidly) - as what if 2 people from companyA are using the service, one in clinic on a fixed IP, one at home on VPN.

Comment: Well my current DNS provider can go as low as 10 minutes on their admin page. I am uncertain about how low you can go, but I did come across one saying 30 seconds. I would say that is a reasonable value for "fast enough".

Comment: I have done site-to-site dynamic routing over VPN in the past, where the site-to-site was sent over whatever link was the fastest and online. Is that what you are aiming for?